# launching the facebook app to a group from iOS

Tags: facebook, ios6

What I am looking to do is launch the facebook iOS App from my iOS App. I can do that with fb://URL but what I need to do is start it off in a facebook group page. It seems like all I can do is launch the app to the users news feed. I have no problem launching safari from my app direct to the group using the URL you normally would use (https://www.facebook.com/groups/group_name) but I would rather have people end up in the iOS app not safari.

I expect I might have have more luck using the facebook API inside my program but think its will be less maintenance in the long run if I let my users just use the official app for being a part of our group.

Answer (score 0):

You are already aware of the existence of the `fb://` url scheme, which is the way to go.

calling it goes like this :

```c
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://<insert function here>"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:theURL];
```

In the place of `<insert function here>`, you could use the following ways to open the facebook app straight to a group of your choice (note that you must use the group *id* rather than its name):

- fb://group/(fbid)/members
- fb://group/(initWithGroupId:)/members
- fb://groups

The last one opens to the groups overview (which you probably do not want), only added that for completeness.

[Akosma has an overview of a great deal of app url schemes for ios here](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)

Comment: I have seen those three options and was along the lines of what I was trying. How do you get the id of the group? I know how to get the ID of a user using the Graph Explorer but that does not work for groups.

Comment: An easy way is to just open the group in your browser, then look at the url :
`https://www.facebook.com/groups/[your group id is here]/`

Comment: It does not show a group id just the group name on the url. Using the group name has not worked on the fb:// urls.

Comment: Wallflux can help you find the group id for a group with a vanity name : http://wallflux.com/facebook_id/

Comment: That got me the id number. I have tried that in the urls and I get "Sorry, this page isn't available" message in the facebook app. Guess I could just stick with launching it in mobil safari, it just seems like a better user experience to use the full facebook app.

Comment: I realize this question and answer are old, but for anyone who comes across this, the pattern fb://profile/<group_id> seems to work just fine in iOS 7 - 9.